# Why does Spring report constructor arg as ambiguous

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

I'm trying to init this map bean:

```
<bean id="totalEventCountStore" class="java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap">
    <constructor-arg type="java.util.Map">
        <map key-type="com.company.EventType" value-type="java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong">
            <entry key="ROUTED_REQUEST">
                <bean class="java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong">
                    <constructor-arg index="0" type="long" value="0"/>
                </bean>
            </entry>

.... more entries .....

</bean>
```

I get:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'totalEventCountStore' defined in class path resource [diagnostics.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [int]: Ambiguous constructor argument types - did you specify the correct bean references as constructor arguments?
```

Does anyone know why this is happening ? `ConcurrentHashMap` has only one constructor that takes a `Map` argument.

Thanks.

Comment: The *"...constructor argument with index 0 of type [int]..."* makes me think it's not the `ConcurrentHashMap` construction, but something else. But the only other thing you've shown is `AtomicLong`, which only has a single constructor accepting anything scalar (although the scalar it accepts is `long` rather than `int`), so I wouldn't think it was the `AtomicLong`. Is there something else involved with `constructor-arg index="0"` and an `int` value that you haven't shown?

Comment: Have you checked whether `<constructor-arg index="0" value="0"/>` is actually the problem? `AtomicLong` takes a long argument in it's constructor, not an int. Mayby you should try `<constructor-arg index="0" type="java.lang.Long" value="0"/>`

Comment: I tried it yes, I get the same error. Actually I'll update my question so people don't get the same idea.

Comment: @Simeon I can't really tell what is wrong, but is it possible for you to move that part of the configuration to Java Config? It will make the code a a lot easier to read and possible easier to debug

Comment: @Simeon, could you extract that bit of the config into a named bean and <ref/> it instead also remove all the ....other entries.... at least that way you confirm if the issue is AtomicLong creation.

Comment: @Simeon: Even after the edit, I'm still wondering whether there's something *else* being constructed in the "more entries" bit with an `[int]` value at index `0`, because again, the error message specifically says it's looking at an `[int]` for that argument, but nothing you've shown is providing one. So it must be elsewhere.

Comment: @James The other entries are exactly the same all atomic longs. I don't think it's the atomic long though as I also tried with the default constructor `<bean class="java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong"/>` and get the same error.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I know ... this is what puzzles me all the other entries are identical atomic long beans, just with different enum value keys.

Answer (score 2):

I am not really sure of what your problem is, but I am sure what it is not : it is not about the `ConcurrentHashMap` initialization, nor about the `AtomicLong`.

Here is an extract of an applicationContext that is successfully loaded by Spring 3.2.4 :

```
<bean id="totalEventCountStore" class="java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap">
<constructor-arg type="java.util.Map">
    <map key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong">
        <entry key="ROUTED_REQUEST">
            <bean class="java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong">
                <constructor-arg index="0" value="0"/>
            </bean>
        </entry>
    </map>
</constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

I just took your code and replaced `com.company.EventType` I didn't have by `String` ... Maybe you should look at `com.company.EventType` because it is the only difference with my test.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the `EventType` is a simple enum. Spring might be trying to use `ordinal()` or something, hence the `[int]`. I'll check this.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't actually an answer, but I found a way that works.

```
<bean id="totalEventCountStore" class="java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap">
    <constructor-arg ref="eventCountInit"/>
</bean>

<util:map id="eventCountInit" map-class="java.util.HashMap" key-type="com.company.RouterDiagnosticEventType" value-type="java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong">
    <entry key="ROUTED_REQUEST">
        <bean class="java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong"/>
    </entry>
    <entry key="ROUTED_REQUEST_WITH_METADATA">
        <bean class="java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong"/>
    </entry>

... more entreies like these ...

</util:map>
```

Still, I don't really know why this way works while the other doesn't, so if someone finds out I'd be really grateful.

And even more puzzling, where does that `[int]` arg come from ?